# Problem with "FrameLabel" when specifying Superscript, Italics, and Times (font)

Tags: plotting, labeling

I'm using FrameLabel to create the label "ln p'(t)" [which is, natural log of the function p'(t)]. This is to be publication quality, so I specify Times font, and Italics (see below). But the "prime" does not italicize (that is, it remains upright rather than slanted). So I try to achieve that end by the Superscript (see below), but that produces " ln (t)p' ". Can someone suggest how to get the proper look for "ln p'(t)" ? Thank you!

```
Graphics[Frame -> True,
FrameLabel -> {"ln " AngleBracket[Style["R(t)", Italic]], 
   "ln " Superscript[Style["p", Italic], ′] Style["(t)", Italic]}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> Times, FontSize -> 16]]
```

Comment: you are multiplying the terms in your label

Comment: It is important to post code that is a minimal working example.  I edited your post for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are multiplying the terms in your label. i.e.

```
"ln " Superscript[Style["p", Italic], ′] Style["(t)", Italic]
```

means

`"ln "` multiplied by `Superscript[Style["p", Italic], ′]` multiplied by  `Style["(t)", Italic]`

Use `Row` to compose the label:

```
Plot[x, {x, 1, 30}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True,
 ImagePadding -> 60,
 FrameLabel -> {Row[{"ln " , AngleBracket[Style["R(t)", Italic]]}], 
   Row[{"ln ", Style[ Superscript["p", \[Prime]], Italic], 
     Style["(t)", Italic]}]}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> Times, FontSize -> 16]]
```